# jQuery syntax, issue with none specific ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am stuck with an issue of syntax in Javascript. Its like this, I am echoing some PHP and getting different ID's from DB. This is my PHP echo...

```
echo "<input type='text' id='form_id_" . $gr_display['id'] . "' />";
```

And it outputs for example

```
<input type='text' id='form_id_X' />
```

And when im clicking a button im starting this JS code, and my question is how to write this code so that im getting the ID of X?

```
 var id=$("#form_id_").val();
```

HTML

```
echo "<form id='edit_form' method='post' action=''>";
echo "<input type='text' id='form_id_" . $gr_display['id'] . "' />";
echo "<input placeholder='New info here' type='text' id='newinfo' name='newinfo'/>";
echo "<input type='button' id='edit_btn'> Button </input>";
echo "</form>";
```

Comment: `$('[id^="form_id_"]')` or use a class =)

Comment: jquery wildcard selector will work for you, see below example
$("[id^=form_id_]").click(function() {
  //do stuff
});

Comment: If im trying to define my variable like this `var id = $('[id^="form_id_"]');` i just get this `[input#form_id_99, input#form_id_94, input#form_id_89, prevObject: n.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "[id^="form_id_"]" in my consol`

Comment: Not helping with classes either. Trying them on both the button and on the input with the id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get the id on click (not sure it is what you want):

**php:**

```
echo "<form id='edit_form' method='post' action=''>";
echo "<input type='text'  class='myInput' id='form_id_" . $gr_display['id'] . "' />";

echo "<input placeholder='New info here' type='text' id='newinfo' name='newinfo'/>";
echo "<input type='button' id='edit_btn'> Button </input>";
echo "</form>";
```

**js:**

```
$("#edit_btn").on("click",function(){
    var id = $(this).prevAll(".myInput").attr("id");
    //or
    id = $(this).prevAll("[id^='form_id_']").attr("id");
    //or
    id= $(this).parent().children(".myInput").attr("id");
    //or if there is only one occurence of .myInput
    id=$(".myInput").attr("id");
    //or if there is only one occurence of [id^='form_id_']
    id = $("[id^='form_id_']").attr("id");
});
```

Comment: That example gives me the ID of the button. I want this `id='form_id_" . $gr_display['id'] . "'` ID.

Comment: then please provide your html because I can't understand without context.

Comment: `<div class="col l6 s12" id="room_list">
   <h5> List rooms </h5>
         <div id="list_room"> </div> <!-- PHP output -->
  </div>
 </div>`

echo "<form id='edit_form' method='post' action=''>";
  
  echo "<input type='text' id='form_id_" . $gr_display['id'] . "' />";
  
  `echo "<input placeholder='New info here' type='text' id='newinfo' name='newinfo'/>";
  echo "<input type='button' id='edit_btn'> Button </input>";
  echo "</form>";`